# Bash decimal to base 62 conversion

Tags: bash, shell, base-conversion, bc

I would like to reverse the operation performed by the following `bash` command:

```
$ echo $((62#a39qrT))
9207903953
```

i.e. convert *decimal 9207903953* to *base 62*, keeping `bash` standard of `{0..9},{a..z},{A..Z}`.

I know I can do this by using `bc`, but I will have to manually convert each character then. For example, I do this currently:

```
BASE62=($(echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}))
for i in $(echo "obase=62; 9207903953" | bc)
do
    echo -n ${BASE62[$i]} #Doesn't work if bc's output contains leading zeroes
done
```

There must be a way to do this in a less 'hackier' way. Do you know of a way to do this more efficiently?

EDIT: changed `bc` input.

Comment: See also [Binary to hexadecimal and decimal in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/binary-to-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-a-shell-script), and [BASH base conversion from decimal to hex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191205/bash-base-conversion-from-decimal-to-hex).  Both have answers that are more general than those titles suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do really appreciate the solution you came up with, and I guess there's no way around it straight with bash. Here's the little point you've missed:

```
BASE62=($(echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}))
for i in $(bc <<< "obase=62; 9207903953"); do
    echo -n ${BASE62[$(( 10#$i ))]}
done && echo
```

Output:

```
a39qrT
```

Comment: The key point is to eliminate the leading zeroes and force base 10, using `$$((10#$i))`. The here-string `$(bc <<< "...")` is fine but not mandatory.

Comment: Here's the symmetrical base62 decode function:
    `function base62_decode() {
      echo $((62#$1))
    }`

Comment: @jsears this doesnt work if the input is too long, you have two's compliment which returns a negative number rather than the correct decimal number. Do you have an alternative to this approach to covert from base-62 to decimal?

Answer (score 4):

```
function base62encode() {
  bc<<<"obase=62;$1" | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%c", $i+(($i<10)?48:(($i<36)?87:29))}'
}
```

- `bc<<<"obase=62;$1"` converts to a sequence of space prefixed decimal numbers from 00 to 61
- then offset each digit into ASCII table and convert to character with awk's printf

Or without the for loop:

```
function base62encode() {
  bc<<<"obase=62;$1" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" +"}/./{printf "%c", $1+(($1<10)?48:(($1<36)?87:29))}';
}
```

Comment: If the editor Bob and the original author Bob are the same: you should use the same account, then you can just edit your answer. If not: the edit should have been a comment, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Or without bc and with arbitrary base:

```
function baseXencode() {
  awk 'BEGIN{b=split(ARGV[1],D,"");n=ARGV[2];do{d=int(n/b);i=D[n-b*d+1];r=i r;n=d}while(n!=0);print r}' "$1" "$2"
}
function base62encode() {
  baseXencode 0123465789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "$1"
}
```

Comment: 1st example doesn't work correctly. e.g. `baseXencode 10 8` returns `0111`

Comment: You specified an inverted base-2 number, it actually works as expected.

Comment: hey man perfectcode ALMOST :) 01234 **65** 789
better reverse this if anyone wants to use this

to test if it works
`echo $((62#$(base62encode 1624429385)))`

should output the same as the input ;D

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary base10 to baseX conversion function using `gforth`, and `tr`, (`tr` is needed since `gforth` and `bash` use different chars to print bases):

```
n2b() { gforth -e "$1 $2 base ! . cr bye" | tr '[0-9A-z]' '[0-9a-zA-Z]' ; }
n2b 9207903953 62
n2b 9207903953 61   # Also works with other bases.
n2b 9207903953 3
```

Output:

```
a39qrT 
aT1PM8
212202201021222121202
```