# How to capture the output of a multi-line Bash snippet into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I found a bit of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471692/bash-base-62-to-decimal-conversion) that can be used to convert bases in bash neatly. How do I use it and get the result into a bash variable?

I tried something like below, but it did not work.

```
NUM_IN_DEC=12321
BASE36=($(echo {0..9} {a..z}))
NAME=(
    for i in $(bc <<< "obase=36; $NUM_IN_DEC"); do
        echo -n ${BASE36[$(( 10#$i ))]};
    done && echo
)
echo converted value is $NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to set `NAME`

```
NUM_IN_DEC=12321
BASE36=($(echo {0..9} {a..z}))
NAME=$(
    for i in $(bc <<< "obase=36; $NUM_IN_DEC"); do
        echo -n ${BASE36[$(( 10#$i ))]};
    done && echo
)
echo converted value is $NAME
9i9
```